# Error in R: Non-conformable arrays, how to fix?

Tags: r

I am trying to create an effect plot for a cox proportional hazards model:

```
fitC7 <- coxph(Surv(TimeDeath, event == 1) ~ 
             strata(sex) * mutation + age
           + ns(BM1, 3), 
           data = data)
```

I created a new dataset as follows:

```
ND1a <- with(data, expand.grid(age = seq(30, 75, length.out = 40), mutation = factor(c("Yes", "No")), sex = factor(c("male", "female")), BM1 = 1.583926))
```

Then, I tried to use the predict function:

```
predict(fitC7, newdata = ND1a, type = "lp", se.fit = T)
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Error in newx - xmeans[match(newstrat, row.names(xmeans)), ] : non-conformable arrays
```

and I do not know how to correct this.

It does work when I put in a model without sex as a stratifier, e.g.,

```
fitC9 <- coxph(Surv(TimeDeath, event ==1) ~
             sex * mutation + age +
             ns(BM1, 3), data = data)
```

I hope someone can help me, I could not figure it out with previous question and answer threads.

Comment: I think `event` in your formula should refer to the whole event column, rather than a (logical) subset. Although it would be easier to help you if you could share (a mockup of) your data.

Comment: Do you mean replacing event ==1 with just event? I tried that, it did not help unfortunately